# Checking if output is empty

Tags: vbscript

I want to check if the output of the netstat command I run in vbscript is empty or not. The below is not working as the port is not in use but it skips past that fact and goes to ERROR (else).

I think it is due to the IsNULL? I could not find what else I could use in vbscript?

```
Set netStatRun = objShell.Exec("cmd /C ""netStat -ano |find ""1002""""")
        netStatOutPut = netStatRun.StdOut.ReadLine
        WScript.Echo "The value is: " & netStatOutPut

            If IsNull(netStatOutPut) Then
                WScript.Echo "The port is free"
            Else
                WScript.Echo "ERROR! Port is use"
            End If
```

OUTPUT:

```
The value is:
ERROR! Port is use
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `IsNull(netStatOutPut)` try using `Len(netStatOutPut) = 0`

```
If Len(netStatOutPut) = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "The port is free"
Else
    WScript.Echo "ERROR! Port is use"
End If
```

You can't use `IsNull` to determine that a string is a zero-length string.

Answer (score 0):

```
If netstatOutput = "" Then
    WScript.Echo "OK: port is free"
Else
    WScript.Echo "ERROR: port is in use"
End If
```